# TypeError: this.state.currentUser.isTypingIn is not a function

Tags: chatkit

I am building a chat app with React and Chat Kit but the above error occurs when I try to implement my realtime indicator. I'd taken the following steps :

I created a stateless component `TypingIndicator.js`

```
` import React, { Component } from 'react'

class TypingIndicator extends Component {
  render() {
if (this.props.usersWhoAreTyping.length > 0) {
  return (
    <div>
      {`${this.props.usersWhoAreTyping
        .slice(0, 2)
        .join(' and ')} is typing`}
    </div>
  )
}
return <div />
 }
}

 export default TypingIndicator`
```

Then I hooked my stateless component above to a `ChatScreen.js`  a container component that manages my application state and renders the UI using presentational - normally stateless - components

```
`import React, { Component } from 'react'
 import Chatkit from '@pusher/chatkit-client'
 import MessageList from './components/MessageList'
 import SendMessageForm from './components/SendMessageForm'
 import TypingIndicator from './components/TypingIndicator'
 import WhosOnlineList from './components/WhosOnlineList'

 class ChatScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props)
  this.state = {
  currentUser: {},
  currentRoom: {},
  messages: [],
  usersWhoAreTyping: [],
}
this.sendMessage = this.sendMessage.bind(this)
this.sendTypingEvent = this.sendTypingEvent.bind(this)
}


sendTypingEvent () {
  this.state.currentUser
  .isTypingIn({ roomId: this.state.currentRoom.id })
  .catch(error => console.error('error', error))
 }

sendMessage(text) {
this.state.currentUser.sendMessage({
  text,
  roomId: this.state.currentRoom.id,
 })
}

componentDidMount () {
const chatManager = new Chatkit.ChatManager({
   instanceLocator: 'v1:us1:aef97d23-a9e1-4eea-955f-3c8a02c98525',
   userId: this.props.currentUsername,
   tokenProvider: new Chatkit.TokenProvider({
    url: 'http://localhost:3001/authenticate',
   }),
 })

chatManager
  .connect()
  .then(currentUser => {
     return currentUser.subscribeToRoom({
      roomId: "19375754",
      messageLimit: 100,
      hooks: {
        onMessage: message => {
          this.setState({
            messages: [...this.state.messages, message],
          })
        },
        onUserStartedTyping: user => {
          this.setState({
            usersWhoAreTyping: [...this.state.usersWhoAreTyping, user.name],
         })
        },
        onUserStoppedTyping: user => {
          this.setState({
            usersWhoAreTyping: this.state.usersWhoAreTyping.filter(
              username => username !== user.name
            ),
          })
        },
        onPresenceChange: () => this.forceUpdate(),
        onUserJoined: () => this.forceUpdate(),
      },
    })
  })
  .then(currentRoom => {
    this.setState({ currentRoom })
   })
  .catch(error => console.error('error', error))
  }

  render() {
   const styles = {
    container: {
    height: '100vh',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  chatContainer: {
    display: 'flex',
    flex: 1,
  },
  whosOnlineListContainer: {
    width: '300px',
    flex: 'none',
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#2c303b',
    color: 'white',
  },
  chatListContainer: {
    padding: 20,
    width: '85%',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
 }

return (
  <div style={styles.container}>
    <div style={styles.chatContainer}>
      <aside style={styles.whosOnlineListContainer}>
        <WhosOnlineList
          currentUser={this.state.currentUser}
          users={this.state.currentRoom.users}
        />
      </aside>
      <section style={styles.chatListContainer}>
          <MessageList
         messages={this.state.messages}
         style={styles.chatList}
        />
       <TypingIndicator usersWhoAreTyping={this.state.usersWhoAreTyping} />
       <SendMessageForm onSubmit={this.sendMessage}
        onChange={this.sendTypingEvent}
        />
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
  )
 }
}

export default ChatScreen
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because is not a function. You're setting the currentUser as an empty object at start, and there's no function in isTypingIn. You should declare isTypingIn as a method of the class and use it wherever you want. It's confusing what do you want to achieve using isTypingIn() as a function when it has not been declared yet.